# Proof about solution to SDE with Lipschitz condition:

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

$X_t$ follows the Ito process as described by the following stochastic differential equation
$$dX_t=b(X_t)dt+dB_t\quad , \quad X_0=x$$

and $b(X)$ satisfies Lipschitz Coditions.I want to show for every  $M>0$ and $t\in[0,\infty)$, we have  $$\mathbb P(X_t\geq M)>0$$

Any help? Any direction?

I'm working with Oksendal "Stochastic Differential Equations# (mostly) and also have Shreve "Stochastic Calculus" and found nothing similar to work with.

Comment: If $b$ is bounded, the assertion is not too difficult to show. Not sure about the unbounded case.

Comment: All I know about b is that it's Lipschitz continuous. I can't assume it's bounded on all line but it will be bounded on every [0,T]